# Unchecked cast from Class

Tags: java, class, generics, unchecked-cast

I have this code:

```
public DriverExtensionFactory(
        Class<? extends AbstractNetworkInterface> serviceClass) {
    super((Class<AbstractNetworkInterface>) serviceClass);
}
```

And it tells me that

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Class<capture#1-of ? extends AbstractNetworkInterface>
to Class<AbstractNetworkInterface>
```

How should I solve this the correct way?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The super class code:

```
public AbstractExtensionFactory(Class<T> serviceClass) {
    service = serviceClass;
}
```

Comment: Show us your super class too.

Comment: That's just the constructor. How about showing your class declaration? Both super class and the `DriverExtensionFactory` class.